# How to retrieve form data information from Header

Tags: jquery, angular

I have angular2+ page that is return from the payment page with the status information in the form data header how I can retrive this information in angular2

in asp.net it is easy to get via Request.form["Key"], how the same thing can be achive in angular/Jquery application

below is the information getting on

[formdata information of Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdRd8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNNsb.jpg)

Comment: Your form data is in the body, not in the header

Comment: yes information is available in the Request Body not in the response body,I attached one more fiddler screen shot...any suggestion how I can do it in angular/Jquery

Comment: Angular cannot read requests, you need to do that on your webserver side

Comment: okay...in this case how I can send the same request to the webapi to read the data??

Comment: The payment gateway's callback url should be one URL handled by your webserver

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using HttpInterceptor(If you need to modify and log the request)

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {

        console.log("intercepted request ... ");

        // Clone the request to add the new header.
        const authReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("headerName", "headerValue")
        });

        console.log("Sending request with new header now ...");

        //send the newly created request
        return next.handle(authReq)
            .catch((error, caught) => {
                //intercept the respons error and displace it to the console
                console.log("Error Occurred");
                console.log(error);
                //return the error to the method that called it
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }) as any;
    }
}
```

more info [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) and [here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Answer (score 0):

you can't get post form data though angular(client-side javascript) browser doesn't make that data available to javascript, but you can use node.js(server-side javascript) or Asp.Net to receive it and redirect to your angular page

1. set payment page redirect URL to your server
2. save payment info in your server
3. redirect to your angular page by your server and pass orderNumber or other fields in your URL, let you can get advanced info from your server
4. use angular send http.get or http.post with orderNumber of prev step to your server
5. receive payment info and do something

[image]